# Problem deleting posts from trash

Tags: trash

My clients has recently had a problem with spam posts being added to their blog, under various usernames. The users have been deleted, but Wordpress is not able to remove the posts from the trash. Using the 'Empty Trash' button does not work either. Removing directly from the database appears to work, but as there are 4000+ entries this would take a long time.

This is Wordpress v3.4.1 and has been upgraded recently.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Does these posts has some common signature, e.g. `date_created` between so and so?

Comment: They were posted on the same date, but none at the exact same time.

Comment: Does the client get an error when they press the empty button?

Comment: The page does eventually blank screen, but I think that is more down to memory maxing out than a corrupted script.

Comment: i also have the same problem on one of my blogs. too many spam posts... i cant delete the users and the posts... always this message "error moving to trash". got now about 5000 posts to delete and nothing works. can anybody help on that? btw, i tried define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0 );... but no luck on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, defining `define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 0 );` in `wp-config.php` file should delete whatever is in *Trash* after zero days. I just tried it, but didn't work immediately. I may have to wait for a day to see the result.

Comment: Yeah I tried that myself, but it didn't work immediately for me either.